# Issues comparing two dates in php

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason I am having difficulties comparing a previous date and current date. I have tried many different things, and tried to google my way to an answer but with no luck.

This is how my code is..

```
$phpdate = date("Y-m-d");

$sql = "SELECT lastDailyCollect FROM users WHERE steamid='".$_POST['steamid']."'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $lastDailyCollect = $row['lastDailyCollect'];
    }
} 

if ($lastDailyCollect == $phpdate) {
//give user error message
}elseif ($lastDailyCollect != $phpdate) {
//let user know it suceeded
}else {
//comparison error
}
```

I want to check if the user is able to collect a daily bonus. The last collection date of each user is stored in a mysql database, in a table called users.
It always goes to the comparison error.

Hope somebody can help.

Comment: what does the $lastDailyCollect look like when you echo it?

Comment: `if ($lastDailyCollect == $phpdate) {` is outside the `if ($result->num_rows > 0) {` statement so it runs - which would likely generate an error - even if the database query fails. Move all that code inside `if ($result->num_rows > 0) { }` and add something like `else { // Could not find user }`

Comment: In the comparison error, I have it echoing the two dates.
<?php echo "MYSQL: ".$lastDailyCollect." PHP: ". $phpdate?> 

It echoes MYSQL: 2017-05-11 PHP: 2017-05-12

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Is `lastDailyCollect` a DATE or a DATETIME type column?

Comment: I use mysqli.
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 if ($conn->connect_error) 
 {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }
Still vulnerable?

lastDailyCollect is a DATE

Comment: Still Vulnerable? YES! Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Try comparing it like `if($lastDailyCollect < $phpdate) { //let user know it suceeded } else { //give user error message }`

Comment: How would I make it not be vulnerable? Doesn't it use mysqli?

Comment: Ambrish Pathak I want it to check if the last collect was the previous day. Not just earlier, and not 24 hours. Just not the same day.

Comment: Will that query return ONE or MANY rows?

Comment: RiggsFolly it returns one row. The query finds one user defined by their unique id.

Comment: Then why are you retrieving the result in a while loop?

Comment: Add this just before the IF `echo "phpdate = $phpdate and lastDailyCollect = $lastDailyCollect";` and show us the result

Comment: Also is `lastDailyCollect` a DATE in so far as you created the column as a DATE type or is it a VARCHAR

Comment: RiggsFolly, phpdate = 2017-05-12 and lastDailyCollect = 2017-05-11

Comment: Throw an intval() on your $_POST['steamid'] for the sql injection protection.  intval($_POST['steamid'])  Assuming the ID is always and ONLY an integer.

Comment: lastDailyCollect is a DATE

Comment: ___It always goes to the comparison error___ Well why are you expecting anything else they are **NOT EQUAL !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!**

Comment: @Fred-ii- Another one for the record books

Comment: @RiggsFolly if you look at the code I provided, there's two checks. One checks if they're equal and one checks if they're not equal. And on top of that, there's an else option. it always goes to the else.

Comment: Not when I run it

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea how you would get code to go to your else based on the IF and ELSEIF covering all possible options

Comment: @RiggsFolly you're probably not getting the data in the same way I am. 
$lastDailyCollect from mysql, a DATE. 
$phpdate from PHP, using date("Y-m-d").

There's no need to try and make a fool of my. Just read the code.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Well done. Now you know why this post was made. It doesn't make sense. Which is why I'm asking for help.

Comment: If I feed those 2 dates into your IF I get into the `!=` i.e. the `else if`

Comment: Maybe you should  look closer at what you are reporting in the `elseif` and the `else` I see no possible way of getting to that `else`

Comment: Obviously. Your point? I know how to compare two strings.
The problem isn't that your code doesn't work, it's that my code doesn't work. You're not getting the data the same way I am.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I was thinking it could be two different data types, and that's why it would go to the else, but I've tried to force both of them into strings with (string) and "".$phpdata

Comment: You just posted the output from the `echo` I suggested. We can see the 2 strings containing a date. Testing is therefore simple

Comment: @RiggsFolly if it was that simple, it would be working, wouldn't it? Clearly it's something else.

Comment: Ok, So clearly, you are not showing all of or all of the relevant code. See how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) emphasis on Verifiable

Comment: Last idea: I have in the past had odd issues like this. In the end I delete the script file and start again. I always put it down to a minimal corruption in the file

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm sure I'm showing all relevant code. Read my previous comment, and let me know your thoughts on that. The one about data types.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I listened to your suggestion and tried redoing it. And guess what, it actually seems to work.
Makes no sense, since I did everything the same, though with different variable names, and no copying anything over.

But seems to work, so thank you.

Comment: :) Well I never.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to check if `lastDailyCollect` date was previous day by subtracting one day from the current date and storing it in `$yesterday` then matching if previous date is equal to `lastDailyCollect` date.

```
<?php

$date = date("Y-m-d");  //2017-05-12

$lastDailyCollect = "2017-05-11";

$yesterday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date . "-1 days")); //2017-05-11

if($lastDailyCollect == $yesterday) {
//give user error message
    echo 'lastDailyCollect is equal to Previous day';
}
else
{
//let user know it suceeded
echo 'lastDailyCollect is not equal to previous day';
}
?>
```

Comment: What if there's more than 1 day since last collect? Then this wouldn't work would it? I just want to check if they collected today, and if they didn't, let them do it.

Comment: Then add `else if($lastDailyCollect < $yesterday) { // more than 1 days since they collected }`

Comment: I redid the whole thing in a new file, and did everything in the exact same way, and it worked. No idea what made the difference, but it's working-